# How to get selected value of a ComboBox binded with enum?

Tags: c#

I am binding `ComboBox` with an Enum type.
I want to get the selected value of Enum on selected index change of a ComboBox.

I am trying like this but it doesn't work.

Enum is like this

```
CategoryType
{
    T=1, 
    D, 
    S
}
```

This is how i fill the combobox

```
custCmb.DataSource = Enum.GetNames(typeof(CategoryType));
```

The selected index change event is like this.

```
private void custCmb_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   categoryType selCustomizationType = Enum.Parse(CategoryType, custCmb.SelectedValue);
}
```

But the above doesn't work I want that numeric value for it.

Comment: How do you fill the combobox? To what do you bind it?

Comment: Could you try `CategoryType selCustomizationType = (CategoryType)custCmb.SelectedValue;` please?

Comment: Cast it: `(CategoryType)Enum.Parse(CategoryType, custCmb.SelectedValue);`

Comment: @lcarus it tells: 'libEPOS.CategoryType' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet see my answer. You forgot to call `typeof(CategoryType)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have tested this and it works fine. You need couple of changes here.

First of all you need to bind with values like below

```
custCmb.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(CategoryType));
```

Then you can get the selected one back as

```
private void custCmb_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CategoryType selCustomizationType = (CategoryType)custCmb.SelectedValue;
    int result = (int)selCustomizationType;
}
```

**Enums are numeric**.

`GetNames` will return a string array containing the field names

`GetValues` will return an int array

Comment: it gives me Topping but cant i get the value 1 for toppiong

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet see my update int result = (int)selCustomizationType;

Comment: the `OP needs to understand what ORDINAL` means other wise your answer looks good

Comment: How GetValus make a differnce over a GetName

Answer (score 1):

For the binding you have to use:

```
custCmb.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(CategoryType));
```

And to have the selected value:

```
private void custCmb_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   CategoryType selCustomizationType = (CategoryType)custCmb.SelectedValue;
}
```

Comment: just edited after seen your initialization code

Comment: look at the posted link where I marked to close for possible duplicate.. the answer you are looking for is right there..

Answer (score 0):

use the `selectedText` instead

```
private void custCmb_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   CategoryType selCustomizationType = Enum.Parse(CategoryType, custCmb.SelectedText);
}
```

Comment: SelectedTExt is always a string, cannot be casted

Comment: sorry about that... @NoviceToDotNet, fixed

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can just cast it if you do this:

```
CategoryType selCustomizationType =(CategoryType)Enum.Parse(typeof(CategoryType), custCmb.SelectedValue);
```

Comment: it says some invalid arguments dont wirk

Comment: it says The best overloaded method match for 'System.Enum.Parse(System.Type, string)' has some invalid arguments